# problems when setting up Shopizer

Tags: java, open-source, shopizer

I was tring to set up the Shopizer on localhost.

I followed [this](http://blog.hexican.com/2011/01/how-to-deploy-shopizer-1-1-2-on-mac-os-x-10-6/) to deploy it. Following is what I did.

1. I think I successfully configured the mysql database. When I run shopizer-build-mysql.bat in the shopizer_root/schema/, there is something wrong with importing the shopizer_data.sql. But I imported it manually.
2. I imported the 4 directory media, sm-core, sm-central and sm-shop into MyEclipse as existing project.
3. right click the build.xml file in each directory, run as Ant. Console said build successfully.
4. copy mysql-connector.jar to Tomcat's lib directory. and copy 3 war files to webapps directory. start Tomcat. Doploying seems right.

Then when I tried to visit localhost:8080/central, I see a logon page. I entered "admin" as login name, and "password" as password. It didnt work, didnt lead me to anywhere.

The console only showed "[DEBUG] (AuthFilter.java:57) [doFilter] - Requested URL /central/profile/logon.action" when I visit localhost:8080/central. When I click "logon", nothing happened.

I dont know what to do now. I want to learn hibernate, spring , struts in a real project. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open profile/logon.jsp

change

window.location.href = "/central/profile/dashboard.action";

to

location.href = "/central/profile/dashboard.action";

Comment: Thank you Mike. I found the solution. The html code about logon button is not working right in Chrome. I deleted some of them, then it works. Also, when I logged into the admin panel, it has something wrong with the js code. For example, in /common/js/formvalidation.jsp, check_select(), form.elements[inputname] doesn't stand for the checked checkbox in Chrome. So it always asks me to select one language.

Answer (score 2):

Some workaround solution for shopizer-1.1.5-src

In chrome:

-fulfill "Logon" form - admin/password

-turn on "Developers tool" - F12

-put in Console: $("#logon-button").click();

-hit Enter

Answer (score 1):

As Shopizer with 2.0 version has switched to maven you can check the [documentation](http://www.shopizer.com/documentation.html#!/) page to correctly set up the app.

> I want to learn hibernate, spring , struts in a real project.

...You can [contribute](http://www.shopizer.com/#!/community) to this project and be a part of the project development, there is no better way to learn than practicing in a real project and developing a useful stuff.